# How can i enter a data that is already in a frequency distribution format to R?

Tags: r

I am talking a statistics course and I wanted to enter this data to R, it is already in the form of frequency distribution.

```
  Data    1 2 3 4 5 6
Frequency 4 7 3 3 2 2
```

Comment: Did you try read.table ?

Comment: please show what you already tried and where you stuck.

Comment: freq_df = data.frame(value = 1:6, frequency = c(4, 7, 3, 3, 2, 2))   then summary(freq_df)  the output is shown as as if the value and the frequency are different statistics on their own.  value        frequency   
 Min.   :1.00   Min.   :2.00  
 1st Qu.:2.25   1st Qu.:2.25  
 Median :3.50   Median :3.00  
 Mean   :3.50   Mean   :3.50  
 3rd Qu.:4.75   3rd Qu.:3.75  
 Max.   :6.00   Max.   :7.00

Comment: what i wanted it to do was, if i were to find the mean, multiply each value by its respective frequency, sum them up and divide by the total frequency

Answer (score 3):

You can use `data.frame`:

```
freq_df = data.frame(value = 1:6, frequency = c(4, 7, 3, 3, 2, 2))
```

On the other hand, if you wish to perform other computations, you might want to reconstruct the original dataset:

```
values_raw <- rep(freq_df$value, times = freq_df$frequency)
print(mean(values_raw)) # mean or other statistics
```

Comment: Ok, but how can i then compute mean, or other numerical techniques, if R doesn't recognize "frequency" as the frequency of the data? Thanks.

Comment: @Mekonenyeab See the update to my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
freq_df = data.frame(value = 1:6, frequency = c(4, 7, 3, 3, 2, 2)) 
result <- with(freq_df, sum(value * frequency)/sum(frequency))
result

#[1] 2.904762
```

This is also called as `weighted.mean`.

```
result <- with(freq_df, weighted.mean(value, frequency))
```